# Class with whitespace in Jade / Pug templating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

Im trying to add a modal window from Bootstap to jade / pug template, but i am failing.

Expected result is :

```
<div id="fa" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

how do i have to format my pug template to achieve this?

```
#fa.????(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle', aria-hidden='true')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [this site](https://html-to-pug.com/) your html produced this pug:

```
#fa.modal.fade(tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle' aria-hidden='true')
```

`#` provides the ID.

`.` denotes a class